# Video loads fine on IPv4 but won't load on IPv6?

Tags: php, video.js

I am using Video.JS as the video player for my test website. I use PHP to fetch the video URL (.mp4) and everything works fine on IPv4. When I test the playback on a device that has IPv6 (like mobile devices and IPv6 enabled wifi networks) the video does not load.

For video.js, the error is that the video format is not supported or the video cannot be found.

I have made sure to enable IPv6 on my server, with the DNS records updated, as well as having an SSL, but the video just fails to load if the ip is IPv6.

Is there anything I need to do with Video.JS to support IPv6?

Comment: What does your browser's network panel and error console say?

Comment: I'm not getting anything in the error log, that's the thing. It's as if it's working so there's no errors, but the video just won't load on IPv6, it will work 100% fine on IPvv4 however